# View above keyboard don't show up

Tags: swift, iphone, xcode

I want to have a View with a textField an a send button above my keyboard, when the keyboard is shown. But this doesn't work.

I already implemented this in my code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.dataSource = self
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow(_:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide(_ :)), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = false

    }

    // MARK: - Keyboard stuff
    @objc func keyboardWillShow(_ notification: NSNotification) {
        let keyboardFrame = (notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as AnyObject).cgRectValue   
        print("hier ist \(keyboardFrame!)")
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1) {
            self.bottomConstraint.constant = keyboardFrame!.height     
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }

    @objc func keyboardWillHide(_ notification: NSNotification) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1) {
            self.bottomConstraint.constant = 0
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }
```

Comment: In iOS, higher value of `y` means lower position on the screen. Probably the order of that constraint items is negative.

Comment: What do you mean exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Check out textField inputAccessoryView.  There's a tutorial [here](https://medium.com/@thedan84/how-to-set-up-a-keyboard-input-accessory-view-programmatically-4f78f0420351) that explains what you're trying to do.